# Cannot upgrade from 10.04.4 lucid to next LTS using terminal or synaptic

Tags: upgrade

it is my first time here in this forum. I am trying to upgrade this ubuntu system to the next LTS version and i am encountering some problems in order to upgrade.

```
cristina@cristina:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists ... done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... done
Correcting dependencies ... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   libc6: Depends: libc-bin (= 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.10) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.2 is installed
          Recommends: libc6-i686
   python-louis: Depends: liblouis0 (> = 1.7.0-2) but it is not installable
   ubuntu-minimal: Depends: libc6-i686
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver :: Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

If i try it with synaptic, the tool gives me 3 broken packages:

`libc6, python-louis and ubuntu-minimal`.

I cannot upgrade this packages using synaptic or doing a apt-get -f install and in the meanwhile i cannot upgrade the system. I cannot upgrade the system with a fresh install.

```
cristina@cristina:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS"
```

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and if you could post your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

Answer (score 0):

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/ubuntu-10-04-12-04-upgrade-how-well-does-it-go

Better use Livecd install it will be faster, go smooth and with no issues, ending with good working OS.